# How to add a default value to json_build_object postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

My json looks like this:-

```
{"DestinationLists": [{"name": "TVNZ, Mediaworks, Choice", "destinations": []}, { "name": "TVNZ, Discovery", "destinations": [165, 183, 4155]}]}
```

My desired output is one row for each object in the array like:-

```
{"name" : "TVNZ, Mediaworks, Choice", "destinations" : []}
{"name" : "TVNZ, Discovery", "destinations" : [{"Id" : 165}, {"Id" : 183}, {"Id" : 4155}]}
```

My query is this:-

```
WITH ExpandedData AS (
    SELECT
        "Id",
        setting,
        json_build_object(
            'name',
             dl->>'name',
             'destinations',
             json_agg(
               json_build_object('Id',dld::text::int)
             )
        ) as DestinationListItem
    FROM
        feature.settings, 
        jsonb_array_elements(value->'DestinationLists') dl,
        jsonb_array_elements(dl->'destinations') dld
    GROUP BY
        "Id",dl->>'name'
)
select * from ExpandedData
```

But this query is missing `destinations` where the array is empty so the result I am getting from the query is:-

```
{"name" : "TVNZ, Discovery", "destinations" : [{"Id" : 165}, {"Id" : 183}, {"Id" : 4155}]}
```

just one row instead of two. How do I update this query to get the desired outcome?

DBFiddle here:- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tDA7SajDoWhXrQaAa1j2qN/0

**EDIT:** I have been able to further drill down my problem, so the issue is basically happening from this line of the query:-

```
jsonb_array_elements(dl->'destinations') dld
```

Basically when the `destinations` array is empty then `jsonb_array_elements` does not return anything so I guess the right solution here would be to somehow return an empty array from `jsonb_array_elements` when an empty array is passed to it.

Comment: Can you prepare a DBfiddle ?

Comment: Hi, updated my question with DB fiddle @IVOGELOV

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68774948/4307136) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive `cte`:

```
with recursive cte(js, ind, r) as (
   select js, 1, case when json_array_length(js -> 'DestinationLists' -> 0 -> 'destinations') = 0 then (js -> 'DestinationLists' -> 0)::jsonb else jsonb_set(js::jsonb, concat('{DestinationLists,', 0, ',destinations}')::text[], (select array_to_json(array_agg(json_build_object('Id', value))) from json_array_elements(js -> 'DestinationLists' -> 0 -> 'destinations'))::jsonb) end from data
   union all
   select js, ind+1, case when json_array_length(js -> 'DestinationLists' -> ind -> 'destinations') = 0 then (js -> 'DestinationLists' -> ind)::jsonb else (jsonb_set(js::jsonb, concat('{DestinationLists,', ind, ',destinations}')::text[], (select array_to_json(array_agg(json_build_object('Id', value))) from json_array_elements(js -> 'DestinationLists' -> ind -> 'destinations'))::jsonb) -> 'DestinationLists' -> ind)::jsonb end from cte where ind < json_array_length(js -> 'DestinationLists')
)
select r from cte;
```

Output:

| r |
| --- |
| {"name": "TVNZ, Mediaworks, Choice", "destinations": []} |
| {"name": "TVNZ, Discovery", "destinations": [{"Id": 165}, {"Id": 183}, {"Id": 4155}]} |

Comment: This bit is a little too complicated for me, I am looking into postgresql for about the first time. Where do I fit the recursive part with my existing query?

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul In essence, your `ExpandedData` cte definition can be replaced with  `cte` from my answer above, and `select * from ExpandedData` can be switched for `select r from cte`

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul Additionally, based on your fiddle, the column name `js` can be replaced with `dest`

Comment: I have updated my question, do you think trying to return an empty array from `jsonb_array_elements` incase the input to it is also an empty array would be a better approach? and is it possible?