# How to remove an object from json on condition Postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

| JsonData |
| --- |
| {"DestinationLists" : [{"name" : "Slingshot", "destinations" : [{"Id" : 4155}, {"Id" : 191}, {"Id" : 165}, {"Id" : 183}]}]} |
| {"DestinationLists" : [{"name" : "TVNZ, Mediaworks, Choice", "destinations" : [{"Id" : null}]}, {"name" : "TVNZ, Discovery", "destinations" : [{"Id" : 165}, {"Id" : 183}, {"Id" : 4155}]}]} |
| {"DestinationLists" : [{"name" : "SecondTest", "destinations" : [{"Id" : 103}, {"Id" : 105}]}, {"name" : "ThirdTest", "destinations" : [{"Id" : 3}, {"Id" : 5}]}]} |

I am trying to write a select query on this data which empties the `destinations` array incase any of the `"Id"` is `null`

So the output should be (empty `destinations` array in second row) :-

| JsonData |
| --- |
| {"DestinationLists" : [{"name" : "Slingshot", "destinations" : [{"Id" : 4155}, {"Id" : 191}, {"Id" : 165}, {"Id" : 183}]}]} |
| {"DestinationLists" : [{"name" : "TVNZ, Mediaworks, Choice", "destinations" : []}, {"name" : "TVNZ, Discovery", "destinations" : [{"Id" : 165}, {"Id" : 183}, {"Id" : 4155}]}]} |
| {"DestinationLists" : [{"name" : "SecondTest", "destinations" : [{"Id" : 103}, {"Id" : 105}]}, {"name" : "ThirdTest", "destinations" : [{"Id" : 3}, {"Id" : 5}]}]} |

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68774948/4307136) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_array_elements` with a subquery to determine if a `"destinations"` key contains any null `Id` values in its array:

```
select json_build_object('DestinationLists', 
    (select array_to_json(
         array_agg(
            case when not exists (select 1 from json_array_elements(v.value -> 'destinations') v1 
                 where (v1.value -> 'Id')::text = 'null')
            then v.value::jsonb
            else jsonb_set(v.value::jsonb, '{destinations}'::text[], '[]'::jsonb) end
        )
     ) 
     from json_array_elements(d1.js -> 'DestinationLists') v)
)
from data d1
```

Output:

| JsonData |
| --- |
| {"DestinationLists" : [{"name" : "Slingshot", "destinations" : [{"Id" : 4155}, {"Id" : 191}, {"Id" : 165}, {"Id" : 183}]}]} |
| {"DestinationLists" : [{"name" : "TVNZ, Mediaworks, Choice", "destinations" : []}, {"name" : "TVNZ, Discovery", "destinations" : [{"Id" : 165}, {"Id" : 183}, {"Id" : 4155}]}]} |
| {"DestinationLists" : [{"name" : "SecondTest", "destinations" : [{"Id" : 103}, {"Id" : 105}]}, {"name" : "ThirdTest", "destinations" : [{"Id" : 3}, {"Id" : 5}]}]} |